# How to check for reversed Pandas DF Columns and add them together

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there a way to check for reversed columns in pandas and then add the reversed columns value to the original rows?

```
Col A    Col B    Value
    A        B        2
    C        D        3
    B        A        2
    E        F        5
```

So the above table would end up with the form

**Expected Output:**

```
Col A    Col B    Value
    A        B        4
    C        D        3
    E        F        5
```

I have tried merging however it doesn't work

Comment: please provide the expected output as code piece

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort column A/B, or apply `frozenset` on them and `.groupby`. For example:

```py
x = (
    df.groupby(df[["Column A", "Column B"]].apply(frozenset, axis=1))
    .agg({"Column A": "first", "Column B": "first", "Value": "sum"})
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
  Column A Column B  Value
0        A        B      4
1        C        D      3
2        E        F      5
```